# Can I keep a folder read by an application in a different location, and use a symbolic link in the original?

Tags: 18.04, symbolic-link

I have a folder SOURCE using by application.

I want to move this folder in a new location without config the new path in the application. So logically, the application read from the source folder but physically, the folder is in another location.

Can I do that using symbolic link?

Comment: Which application? Some applications don't like symbolic links.

Comment: i use a apache web server

Comment: Apache httpd or tomcat? With httpd, the server configuration may deny traversing symlinks.

Comment: apache httpd , use a storage directory to store folder , i want to make that folder outside the www/html folder

Answer (score 0):

I've moved some appdata folders to ~/Private and created symbolic links and everything seems to be working fine:

1. Make sure that the application whose data you want to protect is not running

   ```
   ps -ef | grep evolution
   ```
2. Move the application's data directory into your ~/Private directory

   ```
   mv ~/.evolution ~/Private
   ```
3. Establish a symbolic link from the old location to new location

   ```
   ln -s ~/Private/.evolution ~/.evolution
   ```

The example is using evolution, just change name and paths to what you need.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory